# How do I solve the weighted normal equations?

Tags: polynomials, regression

I am trying to solve the normal equations for a 3D LSE of a  general quadric:
$$ z = ax^2 + bx + cxy + dy^2 + ey + f$$

Write as a vector equation:
$$ \vec{z}= \bf{X}\vec{\beta}$$
where the 'ith row of X is:
$$ Xi = [x^2, x, xy, y^2, y, 1]$$
and
$$ \vec{\beta} =[a, b, c, d, e, f]^T$$

In addition I want to weight the points with the following function:
$$ w(x,y)=(1-(x^2+y^2)^{1.5}/r^3)^3 $$
if
$$ (x^2+y^2) < r^2 $$
0 otherwise (for some user specified distance r).

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29): the normal equations with weights should be:
$$ ({\bf{X}}^T \bf{W} \bf{X}) \vec{\beta}= ({\bf{X}}^T \bf{W}) \vec{z} $$
where W is a diagonal matrix with the n w values along the diagonal.

**How do I solve this equation in a fast and robust manner?**

The wikipage e.g. derives the SVD solution for the non weighted case,
but how is this for the weighted case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me begin by saying that the normal equations are an inefficient method of solving a least squares problem.

Mathematically, the problem which you are trying to solve using the normal equations for $\vec{\beta}$ with no weighting is equivalent to
$$
\vec{\beta}=\operatorname{arg min}\limits_b\;\left\|X\vec{b}-\vec{z}\right\|_2^2.
$$
Expanding this norm under the usual inner product $\langle x,y\rangle=x^Ty$ gives
$$
\left\|X\vec{b}-\vec{z}\right\|_2^2=\vec{b}^TX^TX\vec{b}-2\vec{b}^TX^T\vec{z}+\vec{z}^T\vec{z}.
$$
This is a quadratic form in $\vec{b}$, which can be solved by differentiating this expression wrt $\vec{b}$ and solving the resulting system of linear equations:
$$
X^TX\vec{b}=X^T\vec{z},
$$
which is the derivation of the normal equations.

If the inner product were a non-standard inner product, such as $\langle x,y\rangle_W=x^TWy$, then following the same derivation, you obtain the weighted normal equations:
$$
X^TWX\vec{b}=X^TW\vec{z}.
$$

My reason for this description is that the description of the effect of the non-standard inner product. Following back through the steps, it should become plain that this is equivalent to the following problem, using the standard inner product:
$$
\vec{\beta}=\operatorname{arg min}\limits_b\;\left\|W^{1/2}\left(X\vec{b}-\vec{z}\right)\right\|_2^2.
$$

Now, the [QR decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) can be used to efficiently solve the problem $\min\limits_x\|A\vec{x}-\vec{d}\|$, by factoring $A=QR$, where $Q$ is an orthonormal matrix ($Q^TQ=I$) and $R$ is upper triangular. The linear system becomes
$QR\vec{x}=\vec{d},$
which upon left multiplying by $Q^T$ gives
$$R\vec{x}=Q^T\vec{d},$$
since $Q^TQ=I$. The solution of this linear system $\vec{x}$ is [guaranteed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#Using_for_solution_to_linear_inverse_problems) to be the solution which minimises $\|A\vec{x}-\vec{d}\|$.

The relationship of this to your problem is $A=W^{1/2}X$ and $\vec{d}=W^{1/2}\vec{z}$. This is a much more efficient solution method than the normal equations. It is also numerically superior to the normal equations.

Comment: Thanks Daryl! Just one detail: should it not be: $$R\vec{b}=Q^T\vec{d} $$? Also this is then solved by back substitution since R is upper triangular?

Comment: Also could you recommend a really fast QR C/C++ (or Fortran) implementation? Is the one in Numerical Recepies (qrdcmp) any good?    I guess the Lapack route would be: DGEQRF followed by DTRTRS to do the back substitution?

Comment: @Andy I changed notation slightly when I described the QR algorithm. Where I am solving for $x$, you would be solving for $b$. The fastest routine depends on the size of the problem. The blas/lapack routines will probably be the most efficient for small problems (like yours which has only 6 columns). For larger problems, you should have a look at Krylov Supspace Methods, which are iterative in nature and attempt to calculate the minimum number of orthogonal basis vectors as required.

Comment: Yes, $R$ is upper triangular, so back substitution will suffice.

Comment: Great! Thanks again Daryl.